Loss increasing training neural network in R
I am trying to train a NN with the MNIST dataset in R.
Here is my code:
#Model definition
model = keras_model_sequential() %>% 
    layer_dense(units=512, activation="relu", input_shape = c(784)) %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
    layer_dense(units=256, activation="relu") %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>%
    layer_dense(units=10, activation="softmax")

#Compiling the model
model %>% compile(
  loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics = "accuracy")

#Training the model
history <- model %>% 
  fit(training_set, training_labels, epochs = 20, batch_size = 128, validation_split = 0.2) 

And the result:
375/375 [==============================] - 5s 13ms/step - loss: 0.6692 - accuracy: 0.8330 - val_loss: 0.5425 - val_accuracy: 0.8963

375/375 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 1.9652 - accuracy: 0.8018 - val_loss: 1.2747 - val_accuracy: 0.8893

375/375 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 4.0669 - accuracy: 0.7957 - val_loss: 2.1045 - val_accuracy: 0.8967

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 13ms/step - loss: 6.8282 - accuracy: 0.7900 - val_loss: 4.6619 - val_accuracy: 0.8622

375/375 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 10.4912 - accuracy: 0.7857 - val_loss: 6.5113 - val_accuracy: 0.8552

375/375 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 14.6314 - accuracy: 0.7826 - val_loss: 10.3562 - val_accuracy: 0.8482

375/375 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 19.9495 - accuracy: 0.7766 - val_loss: 9.7781 - val_accuracy: 0.8812

375/375 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 25.2552 - accuracy: 0.7813 - val_loss: 15.7928 - val_accuracy: 0.8535

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 32.1132 - accuracy: 0.7741 - val_loss: 15.4910 - val_accuracy: 0.8721

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 40.7229 - accuracy: 0.7688 - val_loss: 28.9964 - val_accuracy: 0.8351

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 49.3404 - accuracy: 0.7714 - val_loss: 22.8562 - val_accuracy: 0.8758

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 59.3611 - accuracy: 0.7684 - val_loss: 34.9035 - val_accuracy: 0.8493

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 70.3920 - accuracy: 0.7669 - val_loss: 48.6200 - val_accuracy: 0.8295

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 84.2963 - accuracy: 0.7646 - val_loss: 56.1588 - val_accuracy: 0.8312

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 96.0922 - accuracy: 0.7661 - val_loss: 67.7943 - val_accuracy: 0.8315

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 13ms/step - loss: 111.6298 - accuracy: 0.7653 - val_loss: 90.8800 - val_accuracy: 0.8043

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 129.0927 - accuracy: 0.7625 - val_loss: 83.8234 - val_accuracy: 0.8281

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 143.7195 - accuracy: 0.7656 - val_loss: 127.1991 - val_accuracy: 0.8201

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 13ms/step - loss: 164.5980 - accuracy: 0.7643 - val_loss: 139.7128 - val_accuracy: 0.8171

375/375 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 181.1530 - accuracy: 0.7655 - val_loss: 134.1610 - val_accuracy: 0.8253

313/313 [==============================] - 3s 8ms/step - loss: 141.3417 - accuracy: 0.8181

I have tried lower/higher batch size, fewer units in the hidden layers and higher dropout rate. Nothing seemed to solve the issue.
What am i missing?

Try reducing the learning rate.

Unfortunately i see no progress when reducing the learning rate.
